# Does there exist a simple graph that has five vertices each of degree three?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Does there exist a simple graph that has five vertices each of degree three?

I say it does not because according to the rule $2m =$ sum of degrees, where $m$ are the edges. The sum of the degrees is $15$, then $2m = 15$. Then, the number of edges $= \frac{15}{2}$, which is not an integer.

Comment: Correct! $\ \ $

Comment: Well, actually yes there is, but it must have at least six vertices in total :).

Answer (score 4):

As David mentions in the comments, you are correct. The rule you refer to is often called the degree sum formula or the [handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma). The same rule can be used to show the following more general statement:

> Any graph must have an even number of odd vertices.

Here a vertex is called odd if it has odd degree.

Answer (score 0):

actually it does not exit.because according to handshaking theorem twice the edges is the degree.but five vertices of degree 3 which is equal to 3+3+3+3+3=15.it should be an even number and 15 is not an even number and also the number of odd  degree vertices in an undirected graph must be an even count.